# Special format for cite

Tags: bibtex, bst

I need special formatting of references for a student project.(See example)

I tried using **BibTex** with the **these**-style and have almost reached my goal. However, I can't manage to print the author and the year in bold and without the brackets and the little capitals in the bibliography because I don't know how to edit the .bst file.

This is what I get in the text right now: [Gothäll 2017]
And in the bibliographie:

[Diegel 2019] "tab" Diegel, Olaf;...

How can I edit the file or is there another solution to achieve the required formatting?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

If I try using biblatex I only get the abbreviation and not the full name with the full year separated by space and also not in bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
Example for citation \cite{Loftin1980}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My .bib file:

```
@book{Loftin1980,
    title={Subsonic Aircraft: Evolution and the Matching of Size to Performance},
    author={Laurence K. Loftin},
    year={1980},
    series={Reference Publication 1060},
    publisher={NASA}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's usually easier to patch an existing style with `biblatex`.

Comment: So which style would you recommend then for biblatex? The only similar style I found was alphabetic but I didn't manage to customize it.

Comment: Alphabetic or Author-Year. There are othere  paclages (biblatex-apa and so on). Coukd you post a small, compilable as is, code?

Comment: I edited the question and added a small example for the alphabetic style with biblatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer two [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)-based solutions depending on your exact requirements. (Note that in any case I have only implemented the rough look of the style, not the finer details - which are not all visible in the one screenshot from the question anyway.)

If you just want to repeat the citation label in the bibliography, you can use `biblatex-ext`'s `introcite` feature.

Either `introcite=plain`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=plain,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}
sit \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with citation before each bibliography entry. The citations start directly in the entry.]

or `introcite=label`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=label,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}
sit \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with citation before each bibliography entry. The citations are printed as labels before the entries and only run into the space allocated for the entries if they are too long.]

If you want a real tabular bibliography, you can use `biblatex-ext-tabular` and re-use some of the code for the `introcite` feature.

Note that you need to define a new tabular bibliography environment and now use `\printbibtabular` instead of `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
     @{}
     L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     @{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{introcite:typeset}} &
   \driver{} \\}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}
sit \autocite{geer}

\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular bibliography.]