# custom citation style for seminar paper

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I'm struggling to find a matching citation style for my seminar paper because we have strict guidelines on how to have the list of references. I'm a bloody amateur with LaTeX and didn't manage to write my own citation style.

The list of references should be in *alphabetical order of the authors surname* and have the following structure:

> **surname year of publication**: surname, first name: title. place of publication year of publication

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone can help me with this. I'm just completely lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One image of one entry is by far not enough to code a full style, so this can only be a start.

The following captures the main aspects of the style as I see it from the picture. If you need more help, please ask **separate questions** about each change you need to apply.

A good start for customising `biblatex` styles is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

[Special format for cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575816/35864) and [Change Reference appearance with bold authoryear above entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550888/35864) are similar to your desired output, so with a similar approach we might want to try

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=plain,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \usebibmacro{location+date}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nussbaum 1978: Nussbaum, Martha: Aristotle’s „De Motu Animalium“. Princeton 1978.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really really helped me!