# biblatex-ext-tabular with authoryear key

Tags: tables, biblatex-ext

I have been asked to produce a tabular bibliography similar to the following example:

[image: sample bibliography]

This should in theory be possible using `biblatex-ext-tabular`, so I am trying to adapt the MWE in its documentation to my needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
bibstyle=authortitle,%
citestyle=authoryear,%
backend=biber%
%backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
{\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{longtable}{%
@{}
L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
@{}}}
{\end{longtable}}
{\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{tabular:sortname}} &
\driver{\usebibmacro{tabular:omitsortname}} \\}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Aufrecht1859,
title = {Ujjvaladatta's Commentary on the Uṇādisūtras},
titleaddon = {Edited from a Manuscript in the Library of the East India House},
editor = {Theodor Aufrecht},
location = {Bonn},
year = {1859},
}

\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Aufrecht1859}---%
\fullcite{Aufrecht1859}


\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

I guess I would need to know the names of the proper bibmacros in the last two lines of the definition of the `bibtabular` definition, with perhaps some more adjustments. I would appreciate some pointers as to what they would be. Actually, the commands `\cite` for the left side and `\fullcite` for the right side of the table would be producing basically what is needed, if I load biblatex with `bibstyle=authortitle` and `citestyle=authoryear`, so which bibmacros would correspond to them?

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `biblatex-ext` versions of `authoryear` and `authortitle`, you can use the bibmacro `introcite:typeset` to typeset the citation on the left in the table and `\driver{}` to typeset the full bib entry on the right. See also the example in [Special format for cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575816/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
     @{}
     L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     @{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{introcite:typeset}} &
   \driver{} \\}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Aufrecht1859,
  title      = {Ujjvaladatta's Commentary on the Uṇādisūtras},
  titleaddon = {Edited from a Manuscript in the Library of the East India House},
  editor     = {Theodor Aufrecht},
  location   = {Bonn},
  year       = {1859},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Aufrecht1859}

\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular bibliography with author-year citation on the right and full entry on the left.]